# Why is my python unittest script calling my script when I am importing it?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am trying to test a python script and when I import the script into my testing suite, it calls the script. In my example below I import list3rdparty and once I run the test it immediate calls list3rdparty. I do not want this to happen. I would like the test to only call the functions within every test case.

list3rdpartytest.py

```
import unittest
from list3rdparty import * ## this is where the script is being imported


class TestOutputMethods(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_no_args_returns_help(self):
        args = []
        self.assertEqual(get_third_party(args), help())

    ##get_third_party is a function in list3rdparty##


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(warnings = False)
```

list3rdparty.py

```
def get_third_party(args_array):
    ##does a bunch of stuff



def get_args():
    get_third_party(sys.argv)

get_args()
```

Comment: importing a python module always executes the code inside it, this is meant to execute all the method or class definitions inside it, so that they are loaded and ready to be executed themselves. If the module you import is also a script (e.g. meant to be executed from the command line), then you should put the startup code of that script below a `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement, which marks it not to be executed when the file is imported. Usually though my habit is to keep in separate file re-usable things that are meant to be imported and executable things that are meant to be launched.

Comment: Why do people answer the question in a comment? Write an answer!

Comment: @Svend the module I import is also a script. When you say "put the startup code" below a if __name__ == '__main__': statement what do you mean? I am sorry for the ignorance, I am pretty new to python.

Comment: @JacobShafi Just wanted to share this in case you did not know about it, since you mentioned you are just starting off. Within the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) for unittesting, you will see references to mocking. Mocking is a very helpful tool in unittesting that would be worth looking in to. Check out the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=mock#module-unittest.mock)

Comment: @JacobShafi Furthermore, you might want to look in to the best practices of modules and how to best import them. [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). Also from that same link, it would worth it to look over the overall PEP8 style guide. Good luck.

Comment: @idjaw that is super useful! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JacobShafi I'm happy to see @Soviut has provided a satisfactory answer. As a complement, keep in mind that importing a module boils down to executing it. For example the statement `def get_args(): get_third_party(sys.argv)` is executed and results in a method called `get_args` being defined and available in the current scope. In the same way, the last line `get_args()` also gets executed, which is what you want to avoid. The statement `if __name__ == '__main__':` means "if I'm being executed as a script": this statement returns False during an import which prevents `get_args()` to be executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have code at the module level which will be executed on import. For example, if you had a file with the following, it will print the string the first time it's imported.

```
import something
from whatever import another

print 'ding'
```

To avoid this, put the code inside a block like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # your module-level code here
    get_args()
```

This will only run the code if it's being called directly from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am just curious, what do you mean put the code in here. I have been seeing that in other answers but I am not sure what that means. I am sorry for the ignorance, I am new to python.

Comment: Any code that executes at the module-level, so any code not in a function, class or other callable block.

Comment: I have made some edits to show you what I am doing in list3rdparty.rb. So would I just add get_args() under the if __name__ == '__main__': in the test suite?

Comment: @JacobShafi Not quite. Do this -> `if __name__ == '__main__': get_args()` inside `list3rdparty.py`. That way when you import it from `list3rdpartytest.py`, it won't execute the `get_args()`.